# Call function after loading html and js for all objects in A-Frame

Tags: javascript, aframe

I write a projcet with A-Frame.

I want to call a function after initiating of all objects in the scene.

I tried window.onload, but the function is called after loading the HTML, not after the initiating the objects.

Maybe has someone idea to implement it?

https://github.com/LeMueller/skills-lab-web/blob/develop/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Put your code within A-Frame components, it's idea of the framework.

https://aframe.io/docs/0.8.0/introduction/writing-a-component.html

Comment: Thank you for your idea. If I put it in a component, it is called not after all other script.
I use a interval to check the status of loading of other script, if all others are done, the function will be called.

Comment: components are guaranteed to run after 3d scene and entity setup. your method checks script tag loads which does not work and is unrelated to the 3d scene initialization.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it one more time.